# Implementing 2 similar interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface

Is it possible to implement the following 2 interfaces as follows?  This code compiles but after reading about how to implement these, I am not sure if this will work.

```
Interface1
{
   Authorize(string p1, int p2);
   LookupCode(int test);
   GetObject(int ID);
}

Interface2
{
   Authorize(string p1);
   LookupCode(int test);
   GetObject(int ID);
}

class WebService : Interface1, Interface2
{
   Authorize(string p1, int p2)
   {
   }

   Authorize(string p1)
   {
   }

   LookupCode(int test)
   {
   }
   GetObject(int ID)
   {
   }
}
```

Because the Authorize methods have different signatures, could they be correctly mapped to the correct interface?

The other methods that are the same have the same implementation and only 1 instance in the class WebService.  So would this be OK also?

Comment: Of course.  This means you can use this implementation wherever *either* interface is needed.

Comment: This will work if you add the `interface` keyword to the interfaces. :P And yes, the methods will map properly because of their signatures.

Comment: ...and declare return types.

Comment: *I am not sure if this will work.* - I can think of one way to find out. Since the answer to this question is "yes," I'm not sure it's really appropriate for SO...

Comment: And make the implementation methods public (or internal if the interfaces are internal).

Comment: Why didn't you just try this instead of asking here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because the Authorize methods have different signatures, could they be correctly mapped to the correct interface?

Absolutely. In fact, that is *why* they can be correctly mapped each to its own interface, as opposed to the two other methods, which map to both interfaces at once.

Note: The code from your has obvious syntax errors. However, since you mentioned that your code compiles, I assume that your actual code has these errors fixed.

Comment: That's what I thought. And since there is only 1 implementation of the other methods, there is no ambiguity to where those interface methods map to.  The above code is not the actual code that I am using.  I just wanted to display the pertinent facts to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to have different implementation even for same method in both interfaces, you should use explicit interfaces:

```
 interface Interface1
    {
        void Authorize(string p1, int p2);
        void LookupCode(int test);
        void GetObject(int ID);
    }

    interface Interface2
    {
        void Authorize(string p1);
        void LookupCode(int test);
        void GetObject(int ID);
    }

    class WebService : Interface1, Interface2
    {
        public void Authorize(string p1, int p2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Authorize(string p1)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void Interface2.LookupCode(int test)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void Interface2.GetObject(int ID)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void Interface1.LookupCode(int test)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void Interface1.GetObject(int ID)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

but if you don't need repeat yourself, use [interface segregation](http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/9/interface-segregation-principle-isp)